# javascript display words and smoothly animate them

Tags: javascript, gsap

I build something that should display words randomly and animate them.

What I want is a smooth scaling animation and a smooth fading out(blur) animation.

I have almost archive it but doesn't look smooth and I'd love to integrate Greensock using TweenMax with it. Is anyone able to help me to integrate TweenMax with it? 
[

```js
var interval = 600;
var width = 800;
var height = 300;

var words = [
  'Liberty',
  'Morality',
  'Modesty',
  'Curiosity',
  'Imagination',
  'Excitement',
  'Structure',
  'Intellect',
  'Friendliness',
  'Conversation'
];
var wordPlacementInterval = setInterval(function() {
  var currentWord = words.shift();
  if (currentWord) {

    var word = document.createElement('span');

    word.innerHTML = currentWord;
    word.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1) + 'px';
    word.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1) + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(word);
    document.querySelector('#wordcloud').appendChild(word);
  } else {
    clearInterval(wordPlacementInterval);
  }
}, interval);


//Something like this ? how can I implement this?
var scale_tween = TweenMax.to('span', 1, {
  transform: 'scale(.75)',
  ease: Linear.easeNone
});
```

```css
#wordcloud span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  transform: translate3d(-0%, -0%, 0);
  color: #565656;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(1) {
  animation: letterspacing1 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: letterspacing2 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: letterspacing3 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: 1.04s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(4) {
  animation: letterspacing4 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: .9s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(5) {
  animation: letterspacing5 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: .6s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(6) {
  animation: letterspacing6 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: 1.6s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(7) {
  animation: letterspacing7 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: .7s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(8) {
  animation: letterspacing8 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: 1.8s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(9) {
  animation: letterspacing9 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: 2.3s;
}

#wordcloud span:nth-child(10) {
  animation: letterspacing10 5s infinite alternate;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes letterspacing1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing5 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing6 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing7 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing8 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing9 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes letterspacing10 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordcloud"></div>
```

Comment: no matter what you use, if you are scaling elements, their will be jitter. You can try using transform3d to reduce jitter. Please go to greensock tutorials to learn how to use it. Here you can only post bugs that you were not able to resolve.

Comment: Do you have a live reduced sample to look at?. Also use scale directly on the config object, like this `TweenMax.to('span', 1, {scale:0.75, ease:Linear.easeNone})`. GSAP uses for all transform animations the transform matrix and you can add `force3D:true` in the config object to use the full matrix and pass it to the GPU and speed things up.